# NSOperation Causing Crash when Passed to Delegate

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, multithreading, nsoperation

For an iPhone app, I'm using a NSOperationQueue to limit access to the SQLite database to one query at a time. I created a subclass of NSOperation and in the main function I have the following:

```
- (void)main
{    
    // ... other code here ...

    if( [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(queryCompleted:)] )
    {
        [_delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(queryCompleted:) 
                                    withObject:self
                                 waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

Delegate side:

```
- (void)queryCompleted:(QueryOperation*)aQueryOperation
{
     // Breakpoint here allows me to explore and see the members of aQueryOperation

     id results = [aQueryOperation resultSet]; // Crashes here

     // ... more code here ...
}
```

The reason I am passing `self` is to allow the delegate to access the ID for the query operation (in the case where there is more than one request open per delegate) and the results from the query.

In the documentation for `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, it clearly states:

> "This method retains the receiver and the arg parameter until after the selector is performed."

However when the delegate method tries to access the argument, an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" exception is thrown. Any thoughts on why?

Oddly enough, if I set a breakpoint before the crashing reference to the NSOperation object, the debugger permits me to see the object instance and the values of all the parameters.

Comment: I've come up with a temporary (maybe permanent) solution that keeps a local dictionary of operations that I add to my queue. The delegate method then returns an ID for the operation (instead of the reference), and then the reference to the object is retrieved from the local dictionary using the ID.

However, I still don't understand why the above code does not work. Does NSOperationQueue somehow remove all the retain counts from the NSOperation after it is finished executing?

Comment: Maybe post the code from the delegate too? It might be something about the way you're accessing it that's causing a problem.

Comment: Updated post to include the delegate code; it's pretty straight forward. I've since moved onto another model that stores a reference to the operations on the main thread. Working great so far, but I'd still like to know why the approach above did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the waitUntilDone: parameter to YES.  Possibly there is a race condition which is allowing the NSOperation to deallocate itself.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to run with NSZombieEnabled set.  It looks like you are over releasing something somewhere.